# RecyclerView Android Error: E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

When trying to get JSON data from an API and show it on the RecyclerView I'm getting following error:

[image: Error: No adapter attached; skipping layout]

I already use RecyclerView sometimes and I never had this problem.

**MainActivity:**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(activity_main)
    overwriteOnPostInteractionListener()
    setupObservers()
}

private fun setupObservers(){
    mServiceRequest.searchPostsFromAPI().observe(this, Observer { posts ->
        if (posts != null){
            loadRecyclerView()
            mPostList = posts.toMutableList()
        }
    })
}

private fun loadRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.adapter = PostListAdapter(mPostList, mOnPostListInteractionListener)
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
}
```

**Adapter:**

```
class PostListAdapter(private val postList: List<PostModel>,
      private val onPostListInteractionListener: OnPostListInteractionListener):
      RecyclerView.Adapter<PostViewHolder>(){ 

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): PostViewHolder {
    val inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val view = inflate.inflate(R.layout.posts , parent, false)
    return PostViewHolder(view, parent.context, onPostListInteractionListener)
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return postList.count()
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: PostViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.bindTask(postList[position])
}}
```

**ViewHolder:**

```
class PostViewHolder(itemView: View, private val context: Context,
                 private val onPostListInteractionListener: OnPostListInteractionListener)
                : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {

private val postTitle = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.titleTextViewMain)
private val postBody = itemView.findViewById<EditText>(R.id.bodyEditText)

fun bindTask(post: PostModel){
    postTitle.text = post.title
    postBody.setText(post.body)
    postTitle.setOnClickListener {
        onPostListInteractionListener.onListClick(post.id)
    }
}}
```

I searched a lot how to solve this error but I can't.

Comment: u havent called: recyclerview.setadapter(adapter_name);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You build your RecyclerView adapter before feeding the data to the list, so you need to call `mPostList = posts.toMutableList()` before instantiating your adapter.

So, change `setupObservers()` with:

```
private fun setupObservers(){
    mServiceRequest.searchPostsFromAPI().observe(this, Observer { posts ->
        if (posts != null){
            mPostList = posts.toMutableList()
            loadRecyclerView()

        }
    })
}
```

Also set your adapter after, you completely build the `RecyckerView`. So change the order of loadRecyclerView() as below.

```
private fun loadRecyclerView() {
    recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true)
    recyclerView.adapter = PostListAdapter(mPostList, mOnPostListInteractionListener)
}
```

Setting `RecyclerView` adapter before layout can cause issues.

**Side note:**

You instantiate your adapter every time your list is changed, and that's not the right way, and it's better to create your stuff (including the adapter) only once in a lifecycle, and then make setters each time you want to change them instead of instantiating them over and over again.

So, you can instantiate your adapter only once in `onCreate()` method and create a method in your adapter that takes the posts `setPosts(private val postList: List<PostModel>)` and set them internally .. whenever you need to change adapter list, just call `setPosts`

Comment: Nice catch! Also, it will be good to mention that the adapter should be created only once in a lifecycle and then only just pass another list to adapter whenever the dataset needs to be changed.

Comment: @MirunaRadu Totally agree .. I just wanted to target the question issue.. I will modify the answer... thanks for your tip :)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I solved my problem. Following your advice I moved my adapter from loadRecyclerView() to other method that initialize once my adapter into onCreate() and I set the adapter to the recyclerView in loadRecyclerView().